# I am developing a app in kony one studio, in that where can I find the .apk file?

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am developing an app in kony one studio. Where can I find my app's .apk file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After build your app the Kony Studio shows at console the path to the apk. Generally it is at "your_namespace_path/temp/your_app_name/build/your_device_configuration_destiny/dist".